# MsiOpendatabase returns error 110 for patches using jna

Tags: java, java-native-interface, windows-installer, jna

I have the following JNA interface:

```
public interface MsiVersion extends StdCallLibrary {

  MsiVersion INSTANCE = (MsiVersion)Native.loadLibrary( "msi", MsiVersion.class,
      W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS );

  int MsiOpenDatabase( String szDatabasePath,
                       String szPersist,
                       Memory phDatabase );
}
```

If I open an MSI like this everything is fine:

```
int oparationResult = MsiVersion.INSTANCE.MsiOpenDatabase( "example.msi", "0",
    dbPointerMemory );
```

If I try to open a patch I get error code 110. In the documentation, I found that I should somehow pass MSIDBOPEN_READONLY + MSIDBOPEN_PATCHFILE as "szPersist" instead of "0" if I would like to open a patch.

I tried to call the following based on this: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/04/16/577108.html

```
int oparationResult = MsiVersion.INSTANCE.MsiOpenDatabase( "example.msp", "32",
    dbPointerMemory );
```

But is still get error code 110. Can somebody help me to find the correct parameter?

Thanks, 
Bálint

Comment: You can't open a patch with an API designed for MSI/MSM database files. A patch is more like a transform with embedded CAB. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PhilDW _You can't open a patch with an API designed for MSI/MSM database files_ -- Actually the [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370338(v=vs.85).aspx) states that it supports opening patches. Whether or not this makes sense isn't OPs question.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the version number related to the msi/patch. It works well in case of "msi".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that [`MsiOpenDatabase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370338(v=vs.85).aspx) expects a string pointer for the `szPersist` parameter, but in case that a persistence mode is specified, this actually is a **number casted to a string pointer**.

From "msiquery.h":

```
#define MSIDBOPEN_READONLY (LPCTSTR)0
#define MSIDBOPEN_PATCHFILE 32/sizeof(*MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)
```

You are passing the *string literal* "32" to the `szPersist` parameter, but instead you need to pass it a *pointer* that has the value of 32:

```
Pointer openMode = Pointer.createConstant(32);
int operationResult = MsiVersion.INSTANCE.MsiOpenDatabase( "example.msp", openMode, dbPointerMemory );
```

I'm not a Java programmer, so I've just made this up from reading the [reference](https://jna.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#createConstant(int)) and this [FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md) (*How do I get an arbitrary Pointer value?*).

I'm not sure if you also have to change the JNA interface:

```
int MsiOpenDatabase( String szDatabasePath,
                     Pointer szPersist,
                     Memory phDatabase );
```

**NOTE:** As [Heath Stewart explained](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2006/03/31/opening-patch-files-when-compiled-for-unicode/), the definition in the header file "msiquery.h" is incorrect. The value of MSIDBOPEN_PATCHFILE must always be `32`, even if compiling for Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it out but unfortunately, it is not working. I get the same error (error code 110).

Comment: @balint Did you change the interface to use `Pointer` for the 2nd parameter?

Comment: @balint You could also try to use the Unicode version of the API (indicated by `W` suffix) directly, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5314469/7571258). The interface would be `int MsiOpenDatabaseW( WString szDatabasePath, Pointer szPersist, Memory phDatabase );`

Comment: Yes, I used a pointer for the 2nd parameter, I also tried out MsiOpenDatabaseW. Same error, this is very frustrating :)

Comment: @balint Can you exclude other sources of error? Error 110 will also be returned if the file cannot be found, for example. You could check with regular java code first if the file exists. In your example code you are using a relative path for the .msp, you could try to use an absolute path instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into the Ansi/Unicode issue described here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2006/03/31/opening-patch-files-when-compiled-for-unicode/

but to be sure you'd need to say whether you're in Unicode mode or not and your actual value for MSIDBOPEN_PATCHFILE

Comment: Hi, I am not sure but I assume I am working in unicode mode because I open the library with "W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS"